# Make container swipeable on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a container that has images in it, and it has a width bigger than the width of the document window. I added this code

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
        function loop_left(){
            $isotope_container.stop().animate({left:'+=50'}, 500, 'linear', loop_left);
        }  
        function loop_right(){
            $isotope_container.stop().animate({left:'-=50'}, 500, 'linear', loop_right);
        }        
        function stop(){
            $isotope_container.stop();
        }
        if ($isotope_container.width()>$(window).width()) {
            $isotope_container.parent().prepend('<div class="left_scroll"><div class="inner"></div></div>');
            $isotope_container.parent().append('<div class="right_scroll"><div class="inner"></div></div>');

            $isotope_container.parent().find('.left_scroll').hover(loop_left, stop);
            $isotope_container.parent().find('.right_scroll').hover(loop_right, stop);
        }
});
```

It adds a divs that when you hover on them will move the container to the left and right.

Now, this is cool on desktop, but when I'm on mobile this is not that practical. I was looking at mobile jquery, but when i added it, the css included changed the look of my site, so I had to remove it.

Is it possible to make that section swipeable without the mobile.js?

Comment: have you considered making this work by considering separating the functionality between mobile vs desktop, by checking for the window width? I think doing this will limit the functionality to desktop alone as well as allowing you to make any custom work for it in mobile versions. I bet there are a lot of things to consider for the different mobile widths which will be suited to your own preferences.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that, still have to inspect how this will look on mobile tho. I was just wondering if I have some other option for this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest approach will be to check for window width and making responsive modifications (mobile vs desktop) as needed. I highly suggest you code mobile-first for this implementation. Depending on how everything is working in your site, you may have to custom build around that, so I believe adding the below function to your code will simply the process (very simple but highly expandable):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Store the references outside the event handler to optimize
    var $window = $(window);
    var $pane = $('#pane1');
    var customWidth = 400; // change to your needs
    var device = true; // default should be mobile, thus true

    function checkWidth() {
        if ($window.width() < customWidth) {
            //if the window is smaller than the desired width, then return true.
            return true;
        }
        else {
            //if the window is smaller than the desired width, then return false.
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    device = checkWidth();
    // SUGGESTION: Bind event listener to your custom behavior. 
    // If the above function 'resized' your screen instead, you could bind it to
    // the resize function by having it return a desired width instead.
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```